# Shell Script to Delete Selected Directory based on Changing date

Tags: python, shell

My requirement is to delete the previous day directory and create a new directory in the format like as given in the below screen.
We generally make a directory in a below format taking into account the day and the date.
For example:

```
TP1_<TODAY_DAY>_<TODAY_DATE> TP1_TUE_19JUN2018.
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Show what have you tried so far and the specific area you are having difficulties with.  Why have you tagged `python`?  Which shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

to get it into a variable on linux shell you can use the following:

```
export mydate=$(date +%a_%d%b%Y|tr [a-z] [A-Z])
```

then you can use the variable as part of cd, mkdir or any other command, i.e.

```
echo TP1__ TP1_$mydate
```

will give as result, please note that I used it on a Italian Cent OS Linux,

```
TP1__ TP1_MAR_19GIU2018
```